# Random.Next - I don't get it

Tags: .net, vb.net, random

I don't really understand Random.Next(minValue, maxValue).
This always gives me "1":

```
rnd.Next(1,2)
```

However, this seems to create either 1 or 2:

```
rnd.Next(1,3)
```

However, as the second parameter is called "maxValue", shouldn't it also be included in the possible results of Random.Next()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not if the API says it isn't included.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx

Says maxValue is an exclusive value and minValue is inclusive. So no it doesn't include the maxValue.

Edit: This leads to a good teaching point of what to do when using APIs that you are unfamiliar with. Even though variable names should be clear in coding practice to try and help the programmer quickly tell what it is supposed to mean, and what it is used for, it is best practice to also look at the API documentation for that function (if available) to see in further detail exactly what it does. I hope this helps!

Comment: The reasoning behind this is to make it more easier to do things like `someArray[rand.Next(0,someArray.Length)]` Doing that would give you a random element from the entire range of the array and never throw a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` without having to do any aditional math to catch the max and min indexes. There are other "conveniences" but that one is the easiest to show.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rnd as new Random
Dim randv as integer

randv = rnd.next(minValue, maxValue)
```

set "new" to generate more different integer between min and max value

if you set this, youll get many different random integer

```
randv = rnd.next(0, 99999)
```

Comment: Did you even read the question? He knows how use Random.next, he was saying that he was confused about the inclusiveness of the maxValue parameter.